# How can picture of page be straightened out to look as if it was scanned?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, transformation, conceptual

I have seen apps, and wondered how can I programmatically take a picture of image. Define how it needs to be transformed so that it looks parallel to camera and not skewed perspective wise.

Then combine multiple photos to create a pdf file. For example this app does it: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appxy.tinyscan&hl=en

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html

Comment: see [OpenCV Birdseye view without loss of data](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39316776/2521214) so find the edge points and use bilinear or bicubic interpolation to straighten the image

Comment: that was so over my head, visually i can tell what's happening but pretty lost. Any book you recommend that will get me upto speed.

Answer (score 3):

I do not use books for such trivial things so sorry I can not recommend any (especially in English). What you need to do is this:

[image: control points]

1. **input image**
2. **find main contours**

   ideally whole grid but even outer contour will suffice (in case no grid is present). You need to divide the contour into horizontal (Red) and vertical (Green) curves (or set of points).
3. **sample contour curves by 4 "equidistant" points**

   as the image is distorted (not just rotated) then we need to use at least bi-cubic interpolation. For that we need 16 points (Aqua) per patch.
4. **add mirror points to cover whole grid**

   on the image are mirrored (Yellow) points only for horizontal contours you should do this also for vertical contours (did not fit me in the image and did not want to enlarge resolution just for that) and also for the corner points so you got `6x6` control points. The mirror can be done linearly (like I did).

**Now the transformation is done like this:**

1. **Process all pixels `dst(x0,y0)` of target image**
2. **Handle `x,y` as parameter for cubic interpolation**

   if `xs,ys` is target image resolution then:

   ```
   u=(3.0*x)/xs
   v=(3.0*y)/ys
   ```

   Now cubic interpolation is usually done on parameter `t=<0.0,1.0)` so

   if `u=<0.0,1.0>` use `t=u`     and control points `0,1,2,3`.

   if `u=<1.0,2.0)` use `t=u-1.0` and control points `1,2,3,4`

   if `u=<2.0,3.0>` use `t=u-2.0` and control points `2,3,4,5`

   The same goes for vertical contours and `v`. Compute `xi,yi` as bi cubic interpolation of `(u,v)`. And copy pixel:

   ```
   dst(x,y)=src(xi,yi);
   ```

   This is just nearest neighbor but you can also use bilinear for this ... As cubic curve I would use this [polynomial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22582447/2521214).

   The idea behind bi-cubic interpolation is easy. compute point corresponding to parameter `u` on 4 horizontal contours. That will give you 4 control points for the final cubic interpolation in vertical direction and `v` as parameter. Resulting coordinate is your source pixel position.

For more info see:

- [How can i produce multi point linear interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30438865/2521214)
- [Bicubic interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation)
- [OpenCV Birdseye view without loss of data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39316776/2521214)

In case you do not have a grid use any info that can be used as one. For example lines of text can be considered a contour for this ...

Comment: I will get back with any question in 2 days, this is lot of stuff for me so bear with me.

Comment: I had asked this question before and nobody could answer it. This is not trivial, i'd take 6 month course on it and then feel some comfortable.

Comment: I'm a webdeveloper, if you wrote a book on it, id buy it. Something that takes novice programmer in simple english to advanced concepts in image processing like this.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer It is not advanced stuff but fusion of basics in CV/DIP and low level graphics principles. The problem is that most programmers in field are specialized  in their narrow filed and therefore do not see the connections with others... even if they are basic knowledge. Write such book would take between 6 and 12 months, I do not have time will nor mood for such thing not to mention needed funds. I stopped publicating some time ago. Also there should be a lot such books some even online so just google for Computer Vision and Computer graphics.