# How can I transform perspective of object on image?

Tags: python, image, computer-vision, geometry, coordinates

I have a image on which there is object (square). I need to create matrix5x5 of this object, but it can be rectangle.
I need to do it fast and without OpenCV or OpenGl, only using standarts libs of python
I can detect coordinates of corners

Comment: You know that this topic will be closed soon if you don't re-ask the question properly?

Comment: I'm a bit surprised you want a 5×5 matrix, as I'd expect 3×3 for a planar setup or 4×4 for three-space. See also [Finding the Transform matrix from 4 projected points (with Javascript)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/296794/35416) or [Redraw image from 3d perspective to 2d](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14244032/1468366) or [How to match 3D perspective of real photo and object in CSS3 3D transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36050537/1468366) for questions on how to find a certain projective transformation. Is this what you want?

Comment: these might help too: [OpenCV Birdseye view without loss of data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39316776/2521214) and [How can picture of page be straightened out to look as if it was scanned?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42173573/2521214)