# opencv findChessboardCorners fails

Tags: opencv, image-processing

My python code can't find chess board on images. 
I use this code to solve this task:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob

# termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
a = 7
b = 6
objp = np.zeros((b*a,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:a,0:b].T.reshape(-1,2)

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

images = glob.glob('*.jpg')

for fname in images:
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (a,b), None)
    print(fname, ret)

    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    if ret == True:
    objpoints.append(objp)

    cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
    imgpoints.append(corners)

    # Draw and display the corners
    cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (a,b), corners, ret)
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    cv2.waitKey(-1)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I use this test images:

[image: First test image]
[image: Second test image]

And I sucsesfully use findCirclesGrid. What I am doing wrong?
I try to sharpen my images like at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993082/how-to-sharpen-an-image-in-opencv)

**UPDATE 1**

I use such images and findChessboardCorners fails again.
[image: Another test 1]
[image: Another test 2]

When I use Harris Corner Detector it returns many errors and it is difficult to use results of Harris to camera calibration.

Comment: may be this [OpenCV Birdseye view without loss of data](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39316776/2521214) would help a bit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a 9x6 board, not 7x6 board. Change a=9. Border lines are not important.

Comment: I tried it out and it works perfectly. Any particular reason for assigning `a=9`?

Answer (score 1):

***UPDATE:***

As mentioned by Hiroki, I replaced  `a = 9` and it worked perfectly.

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Image 3:

[image]

While using `cv2.findChessboardCorners` the image containing the chessboard must have a border. In the image provided by you there is no border present, hence the function fails. Consider drawing a black border around the chessboard and then perform the same.

In the meantime there is an easier way....

You could have tried using **Harris corner detection** as given in [THIS PAGE](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html#harris-corners)

This is what I obtained as a result:

[image]

Comment: I still don't understand the reason for changing `a=9`. If you come across the reason please post it :D

Comment: a=9 - amount of internal corners =) and b=6 amount of internal corners too. I think, it's good explanation =)

Comment: see above my comment