# Snapping to a corner

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, aforge

Given a small bitmap that resembles a corner or three-way junction, how can the corner point be found?
Some attempt has been made utilizing AForge Imaging to achieve this.
The AForge "BlobsExplorer" sample program shows blob outlines (Convex Hull) surrounding the two major whitespace zones (image example 1).

http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/samples/image_processing.html
https://github.com/cureos/aforge/tree/master/Samples/Imaging/BlobsExplorer

---

[image: 1]

- 0: Source Image
- 1: Default load of Source image with BlobsExplorer
- 2: First Blob highlighted
- 3: Second Blob highlighted
- 4: Point to be found

---

How can the corner point be found based on the two blobs?

There are a bunch of other test images that appear to be properly interpreted by BlobsExplorer - 
I'm hoping the corner point can be found in a similar way.

Test images:

[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]
[image: 6]
[image: 7]
[image: 8]
[image: 9]
[image: 10]
[image: 11]
[image: 13]

Thank you.

Comment: I would approach this differently by scanning whole image and detecting corner points directly similar to this [OpenCV Birdseye view without loss of data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39316776/2521214) bullet **#2 detect square corner points**. instead of cross I would test pixel and its 8 neighboars (in some distance from it) and from combinations decide if it si corner or not ...