# Does opencv have a package for transforming 3D points into a 2D top-down view

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, 3d

Note: I am not asking for projecting a 3D object onto a 2D camera-view image (for which many answers exist).

It's even simpler than that: I have a 3D model of, say, a street. I want to turn that into a street map. So it's a straightforward top-down / bird's eye view, with no camera view. I'm using OpenCV for image processing.

I realize it's straightforward to program this from scratch, but I would like to know if some routine already exists for doing this in OpenCV.

Comment: opencv is for computer vision, not for computer graphics. But afaik there are some functions to project 3D points to camera in openCV. You'll have to compute texturing yourself. Or you just use openGL instead :)

Comment: @Micka thank you: if you write this as an answer in the negative I will accept it!

Comment: You can do it also directly in C++ see [OpenCV Birdseye view without loss of data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39316776/2521214)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV has projectPoints function, but you would have to compute the texturing yourself.

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#void projectPoints(InputArray objectPoints, InputArray rvec, InputArray tvec, InputArray cameraMatrix, InputArray distCoeffs, OutputArray imagePoints, OutputArray jacobian, double aspectRatio)

Using a computer graphics library like openGL might be better.

Comment: doesn't he specifically call out this solution as one he is not interested in? ie camera projection generation of structured image?

Comment: Just think the title/ question may be reworded if this is the answer

Answer (score 1):

I mean transform your "up vector" to match the cartesian z axis and then just run an x y grid sampling taking highest z value per voxel or average