# fix yaw pitch and roll of a panorama picture in three.js

Tags: javascript, math, 3d, three.js

I'm currently working on a VR app based on three.js

The problem I need to solve is that the equirectangular images, that are loaded into the panoramic viewer often have yaw/pitch/roll - which has a huge impact on the rest of the application.

Now I want the user to correct the rotation in an easy, interactive manner (setting yaw/pitch/roll manually as input values drives one mad) and I came up with the following solution:

[image: vizualisation for user interaction]

The idea is to prompt the user to select three points: Two on the floor and one on the ceiling (a point that is above of one of the points on the floor). In the background I get the intersections with the panoramic sphere and calculate yaw/pitch/roll.

Now I got so far to get the intersections (vectors) of the mouse-pano-sphere interaction. However I just don't get the rest working. Tried it with three's lookAt() on the user-selected vectors and to modify the rotatePlane() method of https://codepen.io/maurizzzio/pen/GjAPYj to fit my use case:

```
rotatePlane() {

const vec1 = new Vector3().copy(this.floorPointMain.position).normalize();
const vec2 = new Vector3().copy(this.floorPointOne.position).normalize();
const vec3 = new Vector3().copy(this.ceilingPoint.position).normalize();

const xy = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(vec2, vec1);
const xz = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(vec3, vec1);
const normal = new THREE.Vector3().crossVectors(xy, xz).normalize();
const Z = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);

const axis = new THREE.Vector3().crossVectors(Z, normal).normalize();
const angle = Math.acos(Z.dot(normal));
const q = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(axis, angle);

this.orientationGrid.rotation.setFromQuaternion(q);

this.floorPointOne.rotation.setFromQuaternion(q);
this.floorPointMain.rotation.setFromQuaternion(q);
this.ceilingPoint.rotation.setFromQuaternion(q);

const distanceToPlane = vec1.dot(normal);

}
```

see my current result of above:

[image: img]

However it just won't work and after two days of searching the web and trying a lot, I'm starting to get mad and be very desperate for help.

Please help - with three.js formulas or abstraction help - because I'm not even sure anymore if the very basic idea of solving the rotation problem is right...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: do not use Euler angles for this (they will drive you mad) instead calculate 3 basis vector of your image coordiante system and create [4x4 uniform matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) from it ... Also this [OpenCV Birdseye view without loss of data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39316776/2521214) might help you a bit in case you want to normalize to something planar ... In case you need the euler angles they can be computed from the matrix again if you new the order... Also from the image is not clear what is the cause wrong angles or some distortion instead or both

Comment: Why not just have *two* points, one to determine the camera direction and the other the roll?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog because with fixed center there are 3 degrees of freedom in the sphere surface. you can position point with 2 angles but not a projected rectangle ...

Comment: @Spektre I said 2 *points* not angles. The first provides the yaw + pitch (the spherical polars) and the second the roll.